# Browser Check With Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i wanted to know if possible and a better way of doing this.
I want to use codeigniter to check for a specific browser and browser version so to redirect to a page if the browser is not up to the required for viewing my app, please i wanted to know if this is possible and the best way to achieve this with codeigniter, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [User Agent Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html):

```
if ($this->agent->is_browser('Safari')) {

}
```

If you want to check for a specific version:

```
if ($this->agent->is_browser('Safari') && $this->agent->version() == 5) {

}
```